# Google App Script - OCR pulling google Login Page instead of the content I need

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm having some trouble with OCR extraction

The script is supposed to pull a link to an image from a cell in a google sheet and attempts OCR extraction using it, but the generated OCR file keeps getting the google login page instead of the image I need (And I'm logged in...)

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

As an aside, if I wanted to put the OCR Files into their own folder how would I go about this?

Edit: Shared code

```
var extract_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Extract Data");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(extract_sheet);
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 150;   // Number of rows to process

function doExtract() {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var file_link = row[4];
    var extracted_data = row[6];
    var ocr_file_link = row[7];

    var valueURL = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).getValue();

    var valueURLlength = valueURL.length;
    if (valueURLlength != 0) {
      var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(valueURL).getBlob();

      var file = {
        title: 'OCR File',
        mimeType: 'image/png'
      };

      // OCR is supported for PDF and image formats
      file = Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true});
      var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(file.embedLink);
      var body = doc.getBody().getText();
      //Get link Doc that Generated
      sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 6).setValue(file.embedLink);
      //Get Content of Doc that Generated
      sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 7).setValue(body);
    }
  }
}
```

**Here's how we solved this issue**

Turns out I didn't need to leave google drive at all so I was able to use the Drive File ID instead of a FetchURL.

So I replaced:

`var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(valueURL).getBlob();`

with
`var image = DriveApp.getFileById(file_ID).getBlob();`

And added a `var file_ID = row[1];` after `var row = data[i];`

Hopefully this helps other people who stop by with a similar problem!
Thank you.

Comment: can you share code please?

Comment: @JSmith Added the code, thank ya.

Comment: `UrlFetchApp` doesn't automatically say it's you. You need to provide an authorization header using an OAuth token (that your script can generate) in order to say who is making the request - otherwise it's an anonymous request from a Google IP.

Comment: @tehhowch I thought I was authorizing the application to use my data/credentials when I got the Authorization/permissions popup I hit 'Allow' on the first time I ran the script?

Comment: That authorized the code in the script project. It doesn't authorize external resources, such as a remote URL. `UrlFetchApp` doesn't send cookies or other parameters either, unless you explicitly tell it to do so. So persisting a log-in state and navigating through URL redirects, etc. will be a learning experience.

Comment: @tehhowch Oh that makes sense! I've googled around for adding authorization to the sheet, but I haven't seen anything that works so far.
`var USERNAME = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('username');
  var PASSWORD = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('password');
 var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };
  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers
  };
var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);`

Comment: Character limits are harsh haha - But that's one of the things I tried with no luck. (I did add the script properties, still nothing)

Comment: Consider using https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()

Comment: @Justin What's the link, you're accessing?

Comment: @I'-'I https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1y7PKaFsaZU7ko4-SxqG8reL1HVC2ACNe
would be one of them (A test file) - It likely won't work for you - Part of the issue I realize now is the folder's locked down to specific users, as it should probably stay as the actual files are for work. I could just leave the folder wide open I guess but if I can figure out the OAuth/login method It'd be better for sure.

Thanks for your help on this so far guys.

Comment: @tehhowch tehhowch That link didn't do anything for me unforunately. Spent a good while fiddling with it. Thank you though! :)

Comment: @Justin If the file is already in Drive... Why are you Urlfetching and putting it back in Drive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059696 use `DriveApp` to getBlob

Comment: @I'-'I ...Oh wow. You know I feel prettyyy silly now. Let's call this resolved. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Justin If you worked it out,Post your code with explanation as a answer. It'll help others.

Comment: @justin You should self-answer, rather than edit your question.

Comment: Here's how we solved this issue

Turns out I didn't need to leave google drive at all so I was able to use the Drive File ID instead of a FetchURL.

So I replaced:

`var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch(valueURL).getBlob();`

with `var image = DriveApp.getFileById(file_ID).getBlob();`

And added a `var file_ID = row[1];` after `var row = data[i];`

Hopefully this helps other people who stop by with a similar problem! Thank you.